# Setup to detect duplicate C# code

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I fail to detect duplicate code in sonarq
I've Sonarqube 5.1 up and running and following plugins installed:

- C# [csharp] 4.0
- Issue Assign [issueassign] 1.6
- Issues Density [issuesdensity] 1.0
- Java [java] 3.0
- JavaScript [javascript] 2.5
- German Pack [l10nde] 1.1
- Motion Chart [motionchart] 1.7
- Python [python] 1.5
- Redmine [redmine] 0.2
- ReSharper [resharper] 1.0
- Git [scmgit] 1.0
- Mercurial [scmmercurial] 1.1
- Scm Stats [scmstats] 0.3.1
- SVN [scmsvn] 1.0
- TFS [scmtfs] 1.0
- StyleCop [stylecop] 1.1
- Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects [visualstudio] 1.2
- Web [web] 2.3
- XML [xml] 1.2

sonar-Project.properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=simplecalc
sonar.projectName=Simple Calc
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.visualstudio.enable=true
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=TestResults/*.trx
sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=dotCover.CalcLibrary.UnitTests.html
sonar.sources=.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fail to detect duplicate code" ? Is the widget *Duplication* empty or showing 0% ?

Comment: It is showing 0%, but i have intentionally copied a whole class and put it in a different assembly. There must be duplicated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! As seen in the source code there are two parameters to control the CPD sensor:

- [minimumLines code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/8ed37b59b5b1e954811ef3ca8610cab7eba8b744/sonar-scanner-engine/src/main/java/org/sonar/scanner/sensor/DefaultSensorStorage.java#L446)
- [defaults minimumLines code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/355e940f152a7215f2598f284faa3c27e2591a8a/sonar-scanner-engine/src/main/java/org/sonar/scanner/cpd/deprecated/DefaultCpdBlockIndexer.java#L104-L112)
- [defaults and minimumTokens code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/355e940f152a7215f2598f284faa3c27e2591a8a/sonar-scanner-engine/src/main/java/org/sonar/scanner/cpd/CpdExecutor.java#L147)

Those must be adjusted to fit the needs:

```
sonar.cpd.cs.minimumLines = 1
sonar.cpd.cs.minimumTokens = 1
```

Comment: Those properties are not public on purpose @Thomas because now you're going to generate some noise. Do you confirm that your duplicated pieces of code were located in the same project and were containing at least 10 lines of code ?

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit. Where this settings should be posted. Could you provide example of your properties file. I put thous settings in my file, but look likes results not changed if i have value 1 or 100 which obviously means it's not used for me.